# Не получается создать проект на PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

При создании проекта на Laravel возникает ошибка:
Problem 1 - laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.12.0] require league/flysystem ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.8.0, ..., 3.15.1]. - league/flysystem[3.3.0, ..., 3.14.0] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.11.0]. - league/flysystem[3.15.0, ..., 3.15.1] require league/flysystem-local ^3.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-local[3.15.0]. - league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.2.6) does not satisfy that requirement. - league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.11.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension. - league/flysystem-local 3.15.0 require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension. - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^10.10 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.10.0, v10.10.1, v10.11.0, v10.12.0]. To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files: - C:\Program Files\PHP\php.ini You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode. Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

Версия PHP: 8.2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если windows тебе в php.ini

из `;extension=fileinfo` делаешь это `extension=fileinfo`

из `;extension=openssl` делаешь это `extension=openssl`

из `;extension=zip` делаешь это `extension=zip`

если не знаешь где ini там где php ты установил

а если его нету то делаешь **php.ini-development** это файл надо поименовать в **php.ini** для удобства

> ДААА ЭТО ВСЕ ГДЕ УСТОНОВЛЕН PHP

и в консоль

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
```

Comment: Не помогло. Команда composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app завершается такой же ошибкой

Comment: Можешь скинуть php.ini

Comment: а куда скидывать?

Comment: На Гагал диск или Яндекс а сюда линк

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uh4yqROObi2AV2E-vC-fN1QtP7w6z_IH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: так ты не раскоментил 
;extension=fileinfo                                                                                                              
;extension=zip

Comment: так 929 строчка же

Comment: Да смотри ";" точку запятой удаляй fileinfo иии zip он чють ниже на 961

Comment: как так получается что у меня раскоменчено, а на гугл диск уходит та версия где все закоменчино

Comment: Хм не так робит же

Comment: вот картинка на ней видно что раскомменчино https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-5ZswvEXBcOdcg26PGTZhwf22HBUdhEa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: А zip ? раскоментируй там с 8.2 его тоже на раскосмачивать extension=zip

Comment: да расскомментировал

Comment: а сохрани и посмотри где этот файл где раскосмачено

Comment: теперь расскоменчиные мною модули отображаются так же должно быть PS C:\Windows\System32> php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
Phar
random
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]

Comment: ну вот попробуй установить ларавел

Comment: да и где ты устанавливаешь ларавел чез иде или терминал windows

Comment: ""composer global require laravel/installer ""
""composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app""
Одну их этих пробуй тока запусти через powerShell

Comment: а если у тебя есть OpenServe он херню творит иза чего много чего не робит но там есть терминал можешь через него там установится сто проц.

Comment: сохранил файл через другой текстовый редактор и все заработало, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Ответ есть в тексте ошибки: `"require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension"`

В вашей версии PHP отсутствует расширение `fileinfo`, нужно его включить (раскомментировать в файле `php.ini`). Чтобы найти расположение этого файла, можно выполнить в консоли `php --ini`

Comment: У меня включено extension=curl
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=oci8_19  ; Use with Oracle Database 19 Instant Client
;extension=odbc

Comment: что выдает `php -m` и `php -v`?

Comment: php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
Phar
random
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zlib

[Zend Modules]

Comment: php -v
PHP 8.2.6 (cli) (built: May  9 2023 16:02:16) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

Comment: В списке включенных модулей нет `fileinfo`, так что он скорее всего всё еще отключен и закоментирован. На всякий случай рекомендую попробовать перезагрузить сервер

Comment: я его расскомментировал что делать дальше?

Comment: Сохранить изменения в `php.ini`, перезагрузить apache/nginx, попробовать выполнить `composer install` снова, посмотреть изменилось ли что-то

Comment: команда завершается с такой же ошибкой как указано в вопросе